# Change in Difference from Previous Quarter

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this subset of a data set. I covet to find the Quarter over Quarter change from Q2 to Q3. I am close but unable to cross the finish line. How can I get this done with Pandas?

```
df1

    Store   date_quarter         Revenue    
1    1          2              21036965.58  
2    1          3              18633209.98  
5    2          2              25085123.61  
6    2          3              22396867.61
```

What I have tried:

```
df1['qoq'] = df1['Revenue'].diff()

        Store       date_quarter    Revenue               qoq   
   1      1              2          21036965.58            nan  
   2      1              3          18633209.98         -2403755.60
   5      2              2          25085123.61          6451913.63     <-----Issue
   6      2              3          22396867.61         -2688256.00
```

Requested:

```
    Store   date_quarter         Revenue              qoq
1    1          2              21036965.58            
2    1          3              18633209.98         -2403755.60 
5    2          2              25085123.61  
6    2          3              22396867.61         -2688256.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['qoq'] = df.groupby('Store')['Revenue'].diff()
df
```

Output:

```
   Store  date_quarter      Revenue        qoq
1      1             2  21036965.58        NaN
2      1             3  18633209.98 -2403755.6
5      2             2  25085123.61        NaN
6      2             3  22396867.61 -2688256.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also express it as %change as follows.

```
df['Delta%']=df.groupby(['Store']).Revenue.apply(lambda x:(x.pct_change())*100)



 Store  date_quarter      Revenue     Delta%
1      1             2  21036965.58        NaN
2      1             3  18633209.98 -11.426342
5      2             2  25085123.61        NaN
6      2             3  22396867.61 -10.716535
```